# Can I access to formControl of my custom ControlValueAccessor in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to create a custom form element with ControlValueAccessor interface in Angular 2+. This element would be a wrapper over a `<select>`. Is it possible to propagate the formControl properties to the wrapped element? In my case, the validation state is not getting propagated to nested select as you can see on the attached screenshot.

[image]

My component is available as following:

```
  const OPTIONS_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  multi: true,
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => OptionsComponent)
  };

  @Component({
  providers: [OPTIONS_VALUE_ACCESSOR], 
  selector: 'inf-select[name]',
  templateUrl: './options.component.html'
  })
  export class OptionsComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() disabled = false;
  private propagateChange: Function;
  private onTouched: Function;

  private settingsService: SettingsService;
  selectedValue: any;

  constructor(settingsService: SettingsService) {
  this.settingsService = settingsService;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  if (!this.name) {
  throw new Error('Option name is required. eg.: <options [name]="myOption"></options>>');
  }
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
  this.selectedValue = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  }
```

This is my component template:

```
<select class="form-control"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  (ngModelChange)="propagateChange($event)">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of settingsService.getOption(name)" [value]="option.description">
  {{option.description}}
  </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a plunker?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[SAMPLE PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/PbaklbttCdZkmxHc29KG?p=preview)

I see two options:

1. Propagate the errors from component `FormControl` to `<select>` `FormControl` whenever the `<select>` `FormControl` value changes
2. Propagate the validators from component `FormControl` to `<select>` `FormControl`

Below the following variables are available:

- `selectModel` is the `NgModel` of the `<select>`
- `formControl` is the `FormControl` of the component received as an argument

**Option 1: propagate errors**

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selectModel.control.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.selectModel.control.setErrors(this.formControl.errors);
    });
  }
```

**Option 2: propagate validators**

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selectModel.control.setValidators(this.formControl.validator);
    this.selectModel.control.setAsyncValidators(this.formControl.asyncValidator);
  }
```

The difference between the two is that propagating the errors means having already the errors, while the seconds option involves executing the validators a second time. Some of them, like async validators might be too costly to perform.

**Propagating all properties?**

There is no general solution to propagate all the properties. Various properties are set by various directives, or other means, thus having different lifecycle, which means that require particular handling. Current solution regards propagating validation errors and validators. There are many properties available up there.

Note that you might get different status changes from the `FormControl` instance by subscribing to [`FormControl.statusChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/model.ts). This way you can get whether the the control is `VALID`, `INVALID`, `DISABLED` or `PENDING` (async validation is still running).

**How validation works under the hood?**

Under the hood the validators are applied using directives ([check the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts)). The directives have `providers: [REQUIRED_VALIDATOR]` which means that own hierarchical injector is used to register that validator instance. So depending on the attributes applied on the element, the directives will add validator instances on the injector associated to the target element.

Next, these validators are retrieved by [`NgModel`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts) and [`FormControlDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts).

Validators as well as value accessors are retrieved like:

```
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<Validator|ValidatorFn>,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: Array<AsyncValidator|AsyncValidatorFn>,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR)
```

and respectively:

```
  constructor(@Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<Validator|ValidatorFn>,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: Array<AsyncValidator|AsyncValidatorFn>,
              @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR)
              valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[])
```

Note that `@Self()` is used, therefore own injector (of the element to which the directive is being applied) is used in order to obtain the dependencies.

`NgModel` and `FormControlDirective` have an instance of [`FormControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/model.ts) which actually update the value and execute the validators.

Therefore the main point to interact with is the `FormControl` instance.

Also all validators or value accessors are registered in the injector of the element to which they are applied. This means that the parent should not access that injector. So would be a bad practice to access from current component the injector provided by the `<select>`.

**Sample code for Option 1** (easily replaceable by Option 2)

The following sample has two validators: one which is required and another which is a pattern which forces the option to match "option 3".

[The PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/PbaklbttCdZkmxHc29KG?p=preview)

**options.component.ts**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgModel} from '@angular/forms';
import {SettingsService} from '../settings.service';

const OPTIONS_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  multi: true,
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => OptionsComponent)
};

@Component({
  providers: [OPTIONS_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
  selector: 'inf-select[name]',
  templateUrl: './options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./options.component.scss']
})
export class OptionsComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('selectModel') selectModel: NgModel;
  @Input() formControl: FormControl;

  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() disabled = false;

  private propagateChange: Function;
  private onTouched: Function;

  private settingsService: SettingsService;

  selectedValue: any;

  constructor(settingsService: SettingsService) {
    this.settingsService = settingsService;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.name) {
      throw new Error('Option name is required. eg.: <options [name]="myOption"></options>>');
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selectModel.control.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.selectModel.control.setErrors(this.formControl.errors);
    });
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.selectedValue = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

**options.component.html**

```
<select #selectModel="ngModel"
        class="form-control"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
        (ngModelChange)="propagateChange($event)">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of settingsService.getOption(name)" [value]="option.description">
    {{option.description}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**options.component.scss**

```
:host {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid transparent;

  &.ng-invalid {
    border-color: purple;
  }

  select {
    border: 5px solid transparent;

    &.ng-invalid {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

Define the `FormControl` instance:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public control: FormControl;

  constructor() {
    this.control = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(/^option 3$/), Validators.required]));
  }
...
```

Bind the `FormControl` instance to the component:

```
<inf-select name="myName" [formControl]="control"></inf-select>
```

**Dummy SettingsService**

```
/**
 * TODO remove this class, added just to make injection work
 */
export class SettingsService {

  public getOption(name: string): [{ description: string }] {
    return [
      { description: 'option 1' },
      { description: 'option 2' },
      { description: 'option 3' },
      { description: 'option 4' },
      { description: 'option 5' },
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. However, how do you access `FormControl` when form is constructed through FormBuilder? In your example the component would be invoked this way: `<inf-select formControlName="someControl"></inf-select>`.

Comment: @SlavaFominII let say that you create a `FormGroup` by using `FormBuilder`. Then you can get the control by `formGroup.controls['someControl']` or by `formGroup.get('someControl')`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thank you. I've clarified my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731894/get-access-to-formcontrol-from-the-custom-form-component-in-angular

Comment: It is a very bad practice to use *ngFor with a method (```ngFor="let option of settingsService.getOption(name)"```). It will be being called constantly, even if the returning array is (apparently) the same.

Comment: @adripanico Good point! That implementation is part of the question and I left everything in place intentionally in order for the user to assimilate easily by comparing the two. So I stubbed everything in order to look almost the same.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what in my opinion is the cleanest solution to access FormControl in a `ControlValueAccessor` based component. Solution was based on what is mention [here in Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#-code-ngcontrol-code-).

```html
// parent component template
<my-text-input formControlName="name"></my-text-input>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-text-input',
  template: '<input
    type="text"
    [value]="value"
  />',
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor  {

  // Here is missing standard stuff to implement ControlValueAccessor interface

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (ngControl != null) {
      // Setting the value accessor directly (instead of using
      // the providers) to avoid running into a circular import.
      ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
       const control = this.ngControl && this.ngControl.control;
       if (control) {
          // FormControl should be available here
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me is not working, could you please provide a working example in stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample showing how to get (and re-use) the underlying FormControl and the underlying ControlValueAccessor.

This is useful when wrapping a component (like an input) since you can just re-use the already existing FormControl and ControlValueAccessor that angular creates which lets you avoid having to re-implement it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'resettable-input',
  template: `
     <input type="text" [formControl]="control">
     <button (click)="clearInput()">clear</button>
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: ResettableInputComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class ResettableInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @ViewChild(FormControlDirective, {static: true}) formControlDirective: FormControlDirective;
  @Input() formControl: FormControl;

  @Input() formControlName: string;

  // get hold of FormControl instance no matter formControl or formControlName is given.
  // If formControlName is given, then this.controlContainer.control is the parent FormGroup (or FormArray) instance.
  get control() {
    return this.formControl || this.controlContainer.control.get(this.formControlName);
  }

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  clearInput() {
    this.control.setValue('');
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.registerOnTouched(fn);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(fn);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.writeValue(obj);
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement validation (Validator / NG_VALIDATORS), the AbstractControl is passed into your validation function pretty early.  You can stash that away.

```
  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    this.myControl = c;
```

Comment: This is correct in half. The OP asks for catch the FormControl errors as fast as the FromGroup propagates them. If you use .sertErrors(); from the FormGroup, it will doesn't trigger validate() function.