# I created a Angular custom form control, is it possible to get the FormGroup it belongs to without an Input

Tags: angular

I have a custom control that I have created.

1. It accepts `formControlName="first_name"`
2. it is wrapped in a `<form [formGroup]="userProfileForm">`

It works great.

Is it possible to reference the formGroup from within the custom control's class without adding and input:

```
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731894/get-access-to-formcontrol-from-the-custom-form-component-in-angular) you can inject in the constructor:

```
constructor(el:ElementRef,@Host() @SkipSelf() private control:ControlContainer)
```

So, in ngOnInit in control.control you has the FormGroup

```
ngOnInit()
    {
      console.log(this.control.control.value)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a template name on your `form` element:

```
<form [formGroup]="userProfileForm" #my_form>
```

Then, in your component, you can get this element as a member variable:

```
@ViewChild('my_form') formVariable;
```

Now, you can access the formGroup with:

```
this.formVariable.formGroup
```

from within the component, or

```
formVariable.formGroup
```

from within the template.

**Edit after comment: you don't want tight coupling**

What you describe amounts to inter-components communication: you want components, embedded or not, to exchange informations. The usual and best way to go is with a service and a `Subject` mechanism. See [here in the official Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Comment: That is another way I guess, but still messy and perhaps less reusable than @input.  I am trying to avoid the tight coupling. The goal here is to discover in some way, I thought it must be possibles to infer the formGroup. I am about to dive deeper and will update if i find something.

Comment: Ok, I see. I edited the answer to help you with that.