# Angular Ractive Forms: get validators from custom component

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a custom input component, just a cover for regular html `input` tag.
Here is a usage example:

```
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <my-input [title]="Some title" formControlName="name"></my-input>
  </form>
```

And related component contains:

```
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
```

I managed to access `FormControl` instance from within `my-input` component using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126965/6089515), now what I want to do, is to add an asterisk to `my-input` title if it is required.

The question is - is it possible to access list of validators so I can distinguish `required` validator among them?

P.S. Surely I can put `required` attribute on the element itself

```
<my-input ... required></my-input>
```

But I want use reactive forms.

Comment: Use [NG_VALIDATORS](https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALIDATORS)

Comment: Why don't you set up another property among `<my-input [title]="Some title" [setRequired]="true" formControlName="name"></my-input>` and get in child using `@Input() setRequired: boolean`. In html `<span *ngIf="setRequired">*</span>`

Comment: @varman I just don't want to move validators from component class to template, it feels more reasonable for me to keep the logic inside class

Comment: Have you implemented `ControlValueAccessor` to use `formControlName` on child?

Comment: @varman sure I did, though, I don't think this makes any difference for the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the same issue open in github for a while now (so it seems you are mostly out of luck).

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

You can see solutions like the one below (thanks mtinner from github) but there is nothing official

```
  export const hasRequiredField = (abstractControl: AbstractControl): boolean => {
    if (abstractControl.validator) {
        const validator = abstractControl.validator({}as AbstractControl);
        if (validator && validator.required) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (abstractControl['controls']) {
        for (const controlName in abstractControl['controls']) {
            if (abstractControl['controls'][controlName]) {
                if (hasRequiredField(abstractControl['controls'][controlName])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

You'll see that most people try to solve the same problem as you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Athanasios, thank you for the advice. Haven't seen the issue!

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
<span "formGroup.controls['name'].errors?.required>*</span>
```

Comment: This will hide the asterisk if a user put something in the input, this is not an expected behaviour and bad practice in terms of UX. Thanks for the suggestion though.