# What is the best way to access fromControl within a custom form control

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Inside one of my custom form controls I need to access its formcontrol. It turns out that this is not very straight forward. On the internet I found 3 solutions:

1. Use the validator interface and access the control as followsd

   ```
   public validate(c: FormControl) {
      if (!this.control)
      this.control=c;
      return c?.errors;
   }
   ```
2. Use `inject` or the `Injector` which (in my case) always give a Circular dependency injection error or `No provider for NgControl`

   ```
    this.ngControl = inject(NgControl);
   ```

or

```
this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
```

3. Access the FormControl using @Input

   ```
    @Input() formControl: FormControl;
   ```

This one doesn't work with `formControlName` unfortunately.

So the question is, based on my findings, that I should use 1) or 3). Or is there an other solution?

Comment: Access is via `formControlName` directive https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#properties

Comment: If you do **[formControlName]** you will get a `string`.  Somehow you will need access to the FormGroup to access the formControl using that string

Comment: maybe some of those will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44732530/1527544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote you can get it from `FormControlName` directive applied to your host element.

Keep in mind that this is a circular dependency injection therfore you have to access it in post constuction phase - in my example, it is `ngAfterViewInit` callback

In your custom form control

```
     constructor(@Optional() @Host() private injector: Injector) {
      
      }
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        // setTimeout(() => {
          const formControlName = this.injector.get(FormControlName);
          console.log('ctrl??', formControlName.control);
        //

 });
  }
```

which results in

> ctrl??
> FormControl{validator: ƒ, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, …}

I have forked some random stackblitz example to POC it out.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-form-control-angular-kaoexe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprovince-select%2Fprovince-select.component.ts%3AL49,src%2Fapp%2Fprovince-select%2Fprovince-select.component.html

Ignore errors as those are for other 2 controls that uses `ngModel` and `formControl instead

on the other hand, this is actually the same what you have already tried, it just bypassing circular dependency injection problem thus you can adopt your solution the same way

Comment: Very nice. You can fix those errors by adding **`@Input() formControlName?: string;`**. Then you can check this value before you run the code which you have inside `ngAfterViewInit` ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-form-control-angular-f4pgrm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprovince-select%2Fprovince-select.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fprovince-select%2Fprovince-select.component.html))