# NgbDatePicker inside a custom component, how to propagate validators and styles?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 7 custom component to wrap an ng-bootstrap `NgbDatePickerInput`.

```js
form = this.fb.group({
  date2: [null, Validators.required]
});
```

```html
<date-editor formControlName="date2"></date-editor>
```

**How can I propagate that `formControl`'s `Validator.required` to that inner component?** So that a blank text is invalid and the `<input>` has the `nb-invalid` style applied, exactly like if the datepicker wasn't in a custom control.

[Stackblitz reproduction of my problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5sqjxj).

My custom component is:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'date-editor',
  template: `
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" [(ngModel)]="value" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker" container="body" (focus)="dp.open()" (dateSelect)="update($event)">
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: DateEditorComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DateEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  value;

  propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.value = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { }

  update($event) {
    this.propagateChange($event);
  }
}
```

I've seen [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201298/can-i-access-to-formcontrol-of-my-custom-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-2) and tried working with it, but without success. Clearing the `input` text would not trigger the `ng-invalid` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
(dateSelect)="update($event)"
```

to this:

```
(ngModelChange)="update($event)"
```

[Here is the updated demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9uj1e)

Update:

Add a required attribute to the inner input field.

[Demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9uj1e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts;)

Comment: That does update the model when clearing the textbox, but the css classes remains `<input class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty"...`. I'd like it to become `ng-invalid` to have a visual feedback.

Comment: @dstj just add a required attribute to the input. Update coming to the demo in a moment.

Comment: @dstj And if you would like the styling to go down to the child component as well, then change this `.form-control.ng-invalid` with this `::ng-deep .form-control.ng-invalid`

Comment: thanks. The Demo 2 link is broken it seems. I'll try with `::ng-deep`, but I thought I saw it was deprecated...

Comment: @dstj Fixed the link and removed the `::ng-deep`.