# How to propagate validators and CSS styles to input control inside a custom Angular form component?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have a nested form component with an `<input>` field set up to work with `formControlName="nested"`. The validators are set on the parent `FormControl`, like so:

```js
  form = this.fb.group({
    value: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    nested: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  });
```

I want to propagate the status from the parent `FormControl` to the nested `<input>` so it reacts in the same way as a regular, non-nested `<input>`, *i.e.* when just touching it and clicking submit (which does `control.markAsTouched()`), the status is set to INVALID and the CSS style `ng-invalid` is set.

I managed to get a *partial win* [after reading this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44201298/918244) with the following code that subscribes to status changes of the parent control, but "touching" the nested input will revert it to VALID and clicking Submit will not set the `ng-invalid` style.

```js
@ViewChild('tbNgModel', {static: false}) tbNgModel: NgModel;

private isAlive = true;

constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
        this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ngControl.statusChanges.pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
    ).subscribe(status => {
        console.log('Status changed: ', status, 'Errors: ', this.ngControl.errors);
        this.tbNgModel.control.setErrors(this.ngControl.errors);
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });

    this.ngControl.control.updateValueAndValidity(); // to force emit initial value
}
```

[Stackblitz reproduction of my problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d28achf)

How can I truly propagate the status to the nested control, all while setting the validators only on the parent `FormControl`?

## Final Solution

From @Eliseo's answer and [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57186593/918244), here is the implementation I ended up doing (it works for me, but there may be a better way still)

*component.ts*

```js
    constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
        if (this.ngControl != null) {
            this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
        }
    }

...

    getValidationCss() {
        if (!this.ngControl) return {};

        return {
            'ng-invalid': this.ngControl.invalid,
            'is-invalid': this.ngControl.invalid && this.ngControl.touched,
            'ng-valid': this.ngControl.valid,
            'ng-touched': this.ngControl.touched,
            'ng-untouched': this.ngControl.untouched,
            'ng-pristine': this.ngControl.pristine,
            'ng-dirty': this.ngControl.dirty,
        };
    }
```

*component.html*

```html
...
<input #tb class="form-control" [ngClass]="getValidationCss()" ...>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dstj, the things must be more simple. see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d28achf-s3pxxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnested.component.html)

just in our input we can use [ngClass]

```
<input [ngClass]="{'ng-touched':ngControl.control.touched,'ng-invalid':ngControl.control.invalid}" 
type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" 
       (ngModelChange)="propagateChange($event)"
       (blur)="touched()"
 >
```

Where ngControl is the ngControl inject in the constructor

```
constructor(@Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
        if (this.ngControl != null) {
            this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
        }
    }
```

See that is ngControl who is valid/invalid touched/untouched....

**Updated** add (blur) to mark as touched

**Updated2** using ngDoCheck

Other solution is used ngDoCheck,

Our component

```
  value: string;
  customClass=null;
  onChange:boolean=false;

    constructor(@Self() public ngControl: NgControl,private el:ElementRef) {
        if (this.ngControl != null) {
            this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
        }
    }
  ngDoCheck()
  {
    if (!this.onChange)
    {
      this.onChange=true;
      //it's necesary a setTimeOut to give Angular a chance
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.customClass=this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('class');
        this.onChange=false;
      })
    }
  }
  change(value:any)
  {
    this.propagateChange(value);
    this.touched(null)
  }
```

The .html

```
<input #tbNgModel="ngModel" [ngClass]="customClass" type="text" class="form-control" 
     [(ngModel)]="value" 
     (ngModelChange)="change($event)" 
     (blur)="touched()">
```

Comment: Thanks, but your example doesn't apply `ng-invalid` if you just "cycle" through (touch without changing anything). It seems likes it's missing a "refresh" somewhere as it's set to `ng-valid` even though the `ngControl.control.invalid=true`

Comment: ::glups:: I forgot indicate when is touched, You can use (blur)="touched()". just corrected in stackblitz and in the answer. And yes, the control is invalid, but the input is valid

Comment: Thanks. I still feel having to recode the application of the ng-* CSS classes and the `(blur)` event is weird, but it does work... ;)

Comment: Upon further tests, it only semi-works because the state in the input's underlying `ngModel` remains VALID, so I get `class="ng-valid ng-invalid"` both together. I need the status to be INVALID because in my real app, I also have a custom directive looking for `control.invalid` status to apply boostrap's `is-invalid` CSS class. It doesn't work if the underlying `ngModel` stays VALID. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d28achf-xawuef

Comment: After thinking about the problem, I decided to use DoCheck to copy the class attributes to the input, see my updated answer and the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d28achf-ram9ct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnested.component.html